# How to schedule a task using win32_schedule job class

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, wmi, scheduled-tasks, win32-process

I've to create a class which schedules a task to run at specified time. I know it can be achieved by win32_schedule class create method. Can someone please help me in creating a task which opens at a specified date and time?(Code Sample). Help me with the start time parameter(conversions and all)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a code sample, but it can help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/022e4429-56bc-482c-9a67-af484d6978c1/using-windows-scheduled-tasks-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Sorry this is not what I needed.